# Creating multiple json files with nsJSON

Tags: json, nsis, nsjsonserialization

I'm using the nsJSON plugin in a NSIS installer to create multiple json files.  How do I clear the array between files so that when creating an additional json it doesn't have the values from the prior file.

This a simplified example:

```
nsJSON::Set /value '[]'
nsJSON::Set /value '{ "Input": [ { "test1": false, } ]'
nsJSON::Set /value '{ "Input": [ { "test2": false, } ]'
nsJSON::Serialize /format /file "C:\false.json"

nsJSON::Set /value '[]'
nsJSON::Set /value '{ "Input": [ { "test1": true, } ]'
nsJSON::Set /value '{ "Input": [ { "test2": true, } ]'
nsJSON::Serialize /format /file "C:\true.json"
```

In the above example, the true.json file will have all the set values which are what I would expect given the code but I'm looking for how you clear the array once the data is written to file.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON example is malformed, you are missing a `}` but that does not explain the problem.

It seems nsJSON does not like root arrays.

```
nsJSON::Set /value '{ "Input": [ { "test1": false, } ] }'
nsJSON::Set /value '{}' # <-- Works, it is now just a empty object
```

There is also a Delete command:

```
nsJSON::Set /value '{ "Input": [ { "test1": false, } ] }'
nsJSON::Delete "Input" /end
```

If you absolutely need the root to be an array I think you need to work around the bugs by using the /tree parameter and simply use multiple JSON trees.

I will ask the plug-in author and update this answer if I find a better way to delete the whole tree...

Edit:

A new version of nsJSON has now been released (v1.1.1.0) and it supposedly fixes these issues. Try `nsJSON::Delete /end`

Comment: Thanks, that was the direction I started to go in already, the application uses the JSON as a config and requires the parameters to be at the root.

Comment: I got in touch with the author and he thinks its a bug as well. I'll update when I know more.